# Ember.js - IndexRoute's model

Tags: ember.js

I've been over the guide and some questions around the net. This has to be simple but I'm just missing something..The worst is that other stuff is working out great but not something that should be real trivial (imho).

I have a basic Ember app set up. I have an index template defined, as a landing page. There are elements I want it to reference right off the bat from a 'model' i have as just a javascript object in the script.

```
var company = {
  id: '1',
  name: 'Some Inc.',
  email: 'guy@some-inc.com'
};

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, company) {
    // Set the IndexController's `title`
    controller.set('title', "Publisher Dashboard");
    controller.set('model', company);
  }
});
```

In my HTML I have within the index template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
...
  <span class="name">{{name}} ( {{email}} )</span>
```

I don't know if things have changed over versions. I have seen different syntax do/claim to do the same stuff. I'm using v1.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a model that you are going to use for the IndexRoute

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return 'SOMETHING' //could be 'company'
  },
  setupController: function(controller, company) {
  // Set the IndexController's `title`
  controller.set('title', "Publisher Dashboard");
  controller.set('model', company);
  }
});
```

SetupController model uses the model that is returned by the model hook on the route. So if you return 'company' in the model hook. You will have access to the that company object.

Comment: Thanks Rick! Although actually it was the combination of yours and @fanta's answer.

Comment: That's awesome. It's all about getting your code working. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing this ?

```
setupController: function(controller, company) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  // Set the IndexController's `title`
  controller.set('title', "Publisher Dashboard");
  controller.set('model', company);
}
```

I added one line, which is to call super.

Comment: Thanks fanta! Although actually it was the combination of yours and rick's answer.